# Poetry activates wrong version of python macOS Big Sur

Tags: python, python-3.x, version-control, python-poetry

I'm trying to run a program with poetry but it keeps using the wrong version of python.

when I use

```
poetry shell
```

It outputs

```
The currently activated Python version 3.9.5 is not supported by the project (>=3.10,<3.11).
Trying to find and use a compatible version. 
Using python3 (3.10.4)
```

Which is what I want. It SHOULD use python 3.10. But I don't know why it thinks python 3.9.5 is "activated." But when I use

```
poetry env info
```

It gives me

```
Virtualenv
Python:         3.9.5
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /Users/myname/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/app_name-dNeoDE2I-py3.10
Valid:          True
```

Which is strange, it has a file called py3.10 but it sees as 3.9 and when I use it it runs as 3.9

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried a couple things to remedy this.

```
poetry env use /path/to/my/python/3.10/verion/that/works/outside/poetry
```

Yet, this changes nothing

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this:

```
poetry config virtualenvs.prefer-active-python true
```

Next, remove and create the python virtual environment again. This is what worked for me.

See the documentation please: https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvsprefer-active-python-experimental